# Is there a way for a module to create its required assemblies when it is first run?

Tags: powershell, module

I am trying to write a PowerShell module that relies on a small assembly. The assembly is created from a C# file (`add-type -typeDefinition (get-content -raw xyz.cs) -outputAssembly xyz.dll -outputType library`). Because the module requires this assembly, I have to create the assembly manually when I install the module. I am now wondering if it is possible to have PowerShell execute this `add-type ...` step (or any other module initialization step) automatically when it is first used

Comment: Any particular reason you write the resulting assembly to disk? You could just run `Add-Type` on module import and have it emit into memory

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The reason is that the `*.psm` module file runs with `set-strictMode -version latest` enabled and has a function with two parameter sets that chooses the used parameter set based on the type of class that is defined in the assembly. If I run `add-type`  when the module is imported, the type is known to late (at least it seems so to me) so that the `strict mode` kicks in and errors out because of a seemingly unkown type.

Comment: Both in-memory and to-disk compilation should work in your scenario (see my answer). As an aside: It is advisable to never use `Set-StrictMode -Latest` in _production code_, because future PowerShell versions could introduce additional strictness checks that can break your code. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode#parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, there is no strict need to write a helper assembly *to disk* - creating it *in memory* is sufficient for your use case (omit the `-OutputType` and `-OutputAssembly` arguments, and skip the `Add-Type -LiteralPath` call in the code below).

  - The reason that this suffices is that the existence of types used to declare parameters in a function isn't enforced at the time the function is *defined* (and exported), but rather at the time it is *called* (or its help is invoked or its name is passed to `Get-Command -Syntax`).
- However, you may still want to use the disk-based approach, shown below, so as to incur the performance penalty that the compilation incurs only *once* per machine, the very first time you import the module.

  - Consider also implementing a versioning mechanism so that updates to your module that require an updated type definition recreate the helper assembly when needed.

The following proof of concept uses a stand-alone script module (`./foo.psm1`) whose top-level code tests for the existence of helper assembly `foo.dll` in the same location as the module, and, if not found, creates it with [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type).

The assembly defines sample type `[demo.Foo]`, which the `Use-Foo` module function exported by the module uses as a parameter type.

In real-world usage, with a *directory*-based module, you'd simply point your module manifest's (`*.psd1` file's) `RootModule` entry to the equivalent of the `foo.psm1` file.

```sh
# Create demo module ./foo.psm1
@'

    # Deactivate this to silence the verbose messages.
    $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

    $dllPath = "$PSScriptRoot/foo.dll"
    if (-not (Test-Path $dllPath)) {
      Write-Verbose "Creating assembly $dllPath..."
      Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -OutputType Library -OutputAssembly $dllPath '
        namespace demo {
          public class Foo {
            public string Bar { get { return "I am a Foo instance."; } }
          }
        }
    '  
    }
    else {
      Write-Verbose "Using preexisting $dllPath assembly."
    }

    Write-Verbose "Loading assembly $dllPath..."
    Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $dllPath

    # Define the function to be exported, whose parameter
    # uses the type defined by the helper assembly.
    function Use-Foo {
      param(
        [demo.Foo] $foo
      )
      $foo.Bar
    }

'@ > ./foo.psm1

# Import the module, at which point the top-level code runs,
# which either creates the helper assembly or loads a previously
# created copy.
Import-Module -Force -Verbose ./foo.psm1

Write-Verbose -vb 'Calling Use-Foo...'
Use-Foo ([demo.Foo]::new())
```

Running the above for the first time yields the following, proving that the assembly was created on demand, loaded, and that use of the assembly-defined type as the parameter type of the exported `Use-Foo` function succeeded:

```sh
VERBOSE: Loading module from path '/Users/jdoe/demo/foo.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Creating assembly /Users/jdoe/demo/foo.dll...
VERBOSE: Loading assembly /Users/jdoe/demo/foo.dll...
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Use-Foo'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Use-Foo'.
VERBOSE: Calling Use-Foo...
I am a Foo instance.
```